# Basic php/db password encryption

Tags: php, android, encryption, passwords

've set up two simple php files for a login/register feature on my android app.

I would like to know a simple way to get it to save/write an encrypted password to the mysql database. at the moment its only writing plain text for password.

Code for register.php is :

```
$username = $_POST["username"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];


$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO User (username, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)" );
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sss", $username, $email, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_close($statement);
mysqli_close($con);
```

and code for  login  stuff is:

```
$password = $_POST["password"];
$username = $_POST["username"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM User WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $username, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $userID, $username, $email, $password);

$user = array();

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)) {
    $user[username] = $username;
    $user[email] = $email;
    $user[password] = $password;
}

echo json_encode($user);

mysqli_stmt_close($statement);

mysqli_close($con);
```

very simple question i know but just learning myself. thanks

EDIT:

Based on Jamesking56's link/ response  i've come out with this, but now its not writing to db at all:

```
$username = $_POST["username"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$passwordHash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO User (username, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)" );
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sss", $username, $email, $passwordHash);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_close($statement);
mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: so... use the same "hashing" function? Just not MD5 though ;-)

Comment: PHP did its job because you told it what to do; "store password in plain text". Btw, MD5 is a hash not an encryption algo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using PHP 5.5 or newer, there are some built-in functions for password hashing called `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`.

**Never use MD5 or SHA1 on its own for password hashing** as they can be reversed by using rainbow tables.

You should use a hashing mechanism with a secret that you define which gives you hashes which are unique to your application. The 'secret' you create should never be shared through VCS.

A good article about this can be found here: http://www.phptherightway.com/#password_hashing

---

For anyone using PHP versions lower than 5.5 you can use `crypt()`:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php

*PHP 5.4 will be unsupported as of 14th September 2015 so please consider upgrading to 5.5.*

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function password_hash() in /home/snapchainco/public_html/Register.php on line 7

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using? You can find out by running php -v in the command line

Comment: I dont have a php compiler on ur system but using php in a web server .. and its definitely 5.5 php version

Comment: That error would only appear if the PHP version was lower than 5.5... Is it possible to double-check?

Comment: Unfortunately these methods aren't available in 5.4, try using crypt(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php

Comment: working now!  
with the following code

$username = $_POST["username"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$passwordHash = crypt($password);

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO User (username, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)" );
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sss", $username, $email, $passwordHash);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_close($statement);
mysqli_close($con);

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: No problem! I will update my answer with the PHP < 5.5 answer tomorrow.

Comment: Updated my answer to include PHP < 5.5 version.

Comment: @Will - With PHP version 5.4. you should use `password_hash()` with the [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php). Do **not** use `crypt($password)` because you will end up with a very weak hash (MD5 or DES).